# Why I am request email scope for oauth, Facebook also show I need to access friend list?

Tags: facebook, oauth, scope, oauth-2.0, hybridauth

I am integrating Facebook login in my web app, and I was able to generate a redirect url like..

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fauth%2Fcallbacks%2Foauth2%2F%3Fhauth.done%3DFacebook&state=xxx&scope=email&display=page

As you can see, my requested scope is only *email*.

But when I redirected to FB, I am seeing..

```
xxx would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address.
```

I don't want to scare my users, is it possible not to show *friend list* request?

Comment: Did you read the login documentation? public profile and friend list is the minimum, base permission, you always must request this

Answer (score 1):

With reference to : [Permissions- Basic Info (Default)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-basic-info)-

> Basic info is part of every request for permissions. It includes several elements from a person's public profile and a list of their friends.
>
> A person's public profile refers to the following properties on the user object by default:
>
> - id
> - name
> - first_name
> - last_name
> - link
> - username
> - gender
> - locale
> - age_range
> - Other [public information](https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info#public-info)
>
> The friend list is the friend list node on the user object.